# Java Hexa Complement

Tags: java, hex

How does one obtain the complementary hexadecimal value for a given input ?

This could be a bit more generic, i.e. having an array of X possible values, how do you convert a random array like arr[x] --> arr[arr.length - arr.indexOf(x)].

Please ignore the syntax.

Comment: Do you mean simply reversing the hexadecimal string or reversing an array?

Comment: What do you mean by the "complementary hexadecimal value"? Please explain.

Comment: Are you sure 51FB will be AE04 or AE05?

Comment: @Tapas Bose What do you mean ?

Comment: The code I wrote below follows the procedure described in the first source. I placed 51FB in place of 2D which is giving AE05.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet will find 16 complement of hexadecimal number:

```
BigInteger subtrahend = new BigInteger("2D", 16); 
// input, you can take input from user and use after validation
char[] array = new char[subtrahend.toString(16).length()];
// construct a character array of the given length
Arrays.fill(array, 'F');
// fill the array by F, look at the first source there the FF is subtracted by 2D
BigInteger minuend = new BigInteger(new String(array), 16);
// construct FFF... Biginteger of that length
BigInteger difference = minuend.subtract(subtrahend);
// calculate minus
BigInteger result = difference.add(BigInteger.ONE);
// add one to it
System.out.println(result.toString(16));
// print it in hex format
```

Hope this will help you. Thank you.

Source:

1. [Binary and Hexadecimal Arithmetic](http://www.rwc.uc.edu/koehler/comath/12.html)
2. [Digital Principles and Logic Design](http://books.google.com/books?id=-mLKFXxtZk4C&pg=PA11&dq=hexadecimal%20complement&hl=en&ei=gNYRTvCHGITqrQeY44iIBA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=2&ved=0CCwQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=hexadecimal%20complement&f=false)

---

First find the 15's complement of the given input by subtracting it from the number FF... which is of the same length of the input. Then add 1 to it.